# Django field not populating in admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have just added a new field to one of my models, I have deleted and recreated my database, but when I enter info into the new field, nothing appears to have saved for that field, but the others have.

The field looks like this

```
class Author(models.Model):
    display_name = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=30)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    twitter_handle = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
```

And I have included it into the fields list in forms.py

```
class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ['display_name','first_name','twitter_handle','phone']
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Any help appreciated

Comment: Please post the sources for the entire model and form.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine. Can you provide the rest of your code?
Some databases require that you define a primary_key - depends on your other PKs in the model
Try adding primary_key=True to your display_name field and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED**

Due to a complex interaction between two forms that are submitted at the same time with various validation constraints, I manually populate the models from the forms in a views function, and I had forgotten to add the twitter_hanle to this, oops sorry, hopefully this will help if someone makes the same oversight.